# How to set a value of a Syncfusion SfDropDownList with Selenium and xUnit?

Tags: selenium, blazor, xunit, syncfusion

I'm doing Selenium testing of a Blazor web app and I want to set a value of a SfDropDownList.

I have created an empty Blazor project with SfDropDownList and test project with Selenium and XUnit. Project download url: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/167910/ze/SYncfusionSelenium_b2ea0a0e

```
<SfDropDownList ID="MyDropdown" TValue="string" TItem="Games" Placeholder="Select a game" DataSource="@LocalData">
    <DropDownListFieldSettings Value="ID" Text="Text"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
</SfDropDownList>

@code {
    public class Games
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    List<Games> LocalData = new List<Games> {
        new Games() { ID= "Game1", Text= "American Football" },
        new Games() { ID= "Game2", Text= "Badminton" },
        new Games() { ID= "Game3", Text= "Basketball" },
        new Games() { ID= "Game4", Text= "Cricket" },
        new Games() { ID= "Game5", Text= "Football" },
  };
}
```

This is how I managed to set/change a value of a dropdown: I access a SfDropDownList by ID and set 'Text' from my class "Games". I have to do this 2 times to ensure it is properly set and this is the best I came up with so far.

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("MyDropdown")).SendKeys("Basketball");


Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("MyDropdown")).SendKeys("Basketball");
```

To run Selenium:

1. start server at http://localhost:5000

   - open VS -> select SyncfusionSelenium instead of IIS Server as a Launch option and hit     Ctrl+F5
   - or open project folder -> open console a enter "dotnet watch run debug"
2. Open Tests Explorer and run/debug "Test1"

I would really appreciate some help here as I couldn't find examples how to do this for SfDropDownList .

Useful links:

- https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/167910/selenium-how-to-manage-a-sfdropdownlist-with-selenium
- https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/dropdown-list/getting-started
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/test?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Alex

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve your requirement with help of bUnit test case in the Blazor . It is also the suggested way for handling blazor components .Please refer the following code snippet for your reference.

```
using System;   
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Text;   
using Xunit;   
using Bunit;   
using Syncfusion.Blazor;   
using Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns;   
using Syncfusion.Blazor.Tests.Base;   
using static Bunit.ComponentParameterFactory;   
using Syncfusion.Blazor.Calendars;   
using System.Threading.Tasks;   
using AngleSharp.Css.Dom;   
using Syncfusion.Blazor.Inputs;   
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;   
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;   
using System.Globalization;   
  
private List<Countries> GetDataItems()  
{  
    return new List<Countries>  
    {  
        new Countries() { Name = "Australia", Code = "AU" },  
        new Countries() { Name = "Bermuda", Code = "BM" },  
        new Countries() { Name = "Canada", Code = "CA" },  
        new Countries() { Name = "Cameroon", Code = "CM" },  
        new Countries() { Name = "Denmark", Code = "DK" },  
        new Countries() { Name = "France", Code = "FR" }  
    };  
}  
  
[Fact(DisplayName = "Value at dynamic changes")]  
public async Task DynamicValueBinding()  
{  
    var data = GetDataItems();  
    var dropdown = RenderComponent<SfDropDownList<string, Countries>>(parameters =>  
            parameters.Add(p => p.DataSource, data).AddChildContent<DropDownListFieldSettings>(field => field.Add(p => p.Text, "Name").Add(p => p.Value, "Code")));  
    dropdown.SetParametersAndRender(("Value", "AU"));  
    await Task.Delay(200);  
    var inputEle = dropdown.Find("input");  
    Assert.Equal(dropdown.Instance.Text, inputEle.GetAttribute("value"));  
    Assert.Equal(0, dropdown.Instance.Index);  
    dropdown.SetParametersAndRender(("Value", null));  
    Assert.Equal(dropdown.Instance.Text, inputEle.GetAttribute("value"));  
    Assert.Null(dropdown.Instance.Value);  
    Assert.Null(dropdown.Instance.Index);  
    dropdown.SetParametersAndRender(("Index", 3));  
    await Task.Delay(200);  
    inputEle = dropdown.Find("input");  
    Assert.Equal("CM", dropdown.Instance.Value);  
    Assert.Equal(3, dropdown.Instance.Index);  
    dropdown.SetParametersAndRender(("Index", null));  
    Assert.Null(dropdown.Instance.Value);  
    Assert.Null(dropdown.Instance.Index);  
}
```